# Multiple `addCircleMarkers` layers using Leaflet in R?

Tags: r, leaflet

When using Leaflet in R, I assumed that plotting layers (ala ggplot) would be effective:

```
 m <- leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addCircleMarkers(lat=subset(DF, outcome=='W')$lat, lng=subset(DF, outcome=='W')$lon, color= "red") %>%
      addCircleMarkers(lat=subset(DF, outcome=='L')$lat, lng=subset(DF, outcome=='L')$lon, color= "blue")
```

I had assumed that this would give me two different colored circle markers, red markers for those records that had 'W' outcomes, and blue markers for records that had 'L' outcomes.

Instead, I don't get any map at all.

How can I pipe multiple `addCircleMarkers` in sequence using Leaflet in R?

Answer (score 11):

Pipelining is straight forward. The following code works for me.

```
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(lng = 9, lat = 47, color = 'red') %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(lng = 8.5, lat = 47.5, color = 'blue')
```

Also your example code works fine with a sample data frame:

```
DF <- data.frame(lat = c(47,48), lon = c(8,9), outcome = c("W", "L"))
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(
    lat=subset(DF, outcome=='W')$lat, lng=subset(DF,outcome=='W')$lon, 
    color= "red") %>%
  addCircleMarkers(
    lat=subset(DF, outcome=='L')$lat, lng=subset(DF, outcome=='L')$lon, 
    color= "blue")
```

This gives the following map
[image: leaflet sample with multiple layers addCircleMarkers()]

Comment: This is great...but I've noticed there can be problems when not all classes exist -- eg, there are no Reds, only Blue. The solution to the question linked here addresses this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32031432/leaflet-in-r-plotting-icons-unpredictably